# C#: Load roaming profile and execute program as user

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation, runas, roaming-profile

In an application I need to execute other programs with another user's credentials. Currently I use **[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx)** to execute the program:

```
public static Process Start(
   string fileName,
   string arguments,
   string userName,
   SecureString password,
   string domain
)
```

However this function does not load the roaming profile from the net - which is required.

I could use "runas /profile ..." to load the profile and execute the command, but that would ask for a password. There must be an more elegant way...

But where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.loaduserprofile.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

My solution (based on leppie's hint):

```
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = textFilename.Text;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = textArgument.Text;
        p.StartInfo.UserName = textUsername.Text;
        p.StartInfo.Domain = textDomain.Text;
        p.StartInfo.Password = securePassword.SecureText;

        p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        try {
            p.Start();
        } catch (Win32Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Nice, I think more people should post their final solutions  :)